# Передача данных из java в 1с и обратно через intent'ы

Tags: java, android, 1с

Всех приветствую. Есть мобильное android приложение 1С.

Нужно, чтобы оно могло отправлять какие-то действия приложению на java, при этом тело действий должно содержать какие-то данные.

То же самое нужно сделать и обратно: нужно java приложением по вызову какого-то действия отдавать 1С приложению данные через intent.

Единственная мысль - на стороне Java использовать broadcastreceiver, но, опять же, куда потом отправлять intent с данными (на стороне java)? 1С, вроде как, не поддерживает (не имеет) аналога android'овского broadcastreceiver'a

Еще была мысль поднять локальный TCP сервер в сервисе android'a, слушать там клиентов, получать данные, отвечать на них, отправлять данные клиенту в ответ.

Есть какие-то более адекватные решения данной проблемы?

Comment: 1С приложение ваше? Если нет, то обращайтесь к его разработчику. Без его участия не о чем и говорить.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, нет, 1С не мое, но связь с разработчиком есть. Хотелось бы узнать какое-то нормальное решение данной проблемы, без использования tcp сервера. Хотя, возможно, это единственное рабочее решение...

Comment: Многое зависит от типа и обьема данных. Для простых данных, которые можно представить как текст (JSON, Base64, XML), вполне достаточно обычных интентов: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing